# JBoss EAP 6.4 - Maven Deploy war not in Deployments

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly

Have JBOSS EAP 6.4 setup on my local Unix (macOS) environment...

Checked out the following helloworld project from Github:

https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/7.1.x-develop/helloworld-rs

Was able to build and deploy the war file into JBoss by issuing the following command:

```
mvn clean wildfly:deploy -Dwildfly.port=9999
```

Was able to hit the REST endpoint by putting this in my browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/jboss-helloworld-rs/rest/json
```

Response was:

```
{"result":"Hello World!"}
```

However, inside $EAP_HOME/standalone/deployments (and also $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments), the directory is empty...

Question(s):

1. Why can I not see the war file (whether packed or unpacked) inside the deployments dir?
2. Is there a way to change a setting somewhere so the war file can be seen?
3. Is there a way to change this pom.xml file so I can just use:

   mvn jboss-as:deploy
4. Is JBOSS EAP 6's codename wildfly?

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: What is it you want to see in the deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `standalone/deployments` directory is only used for deployment scanner. It's not advised to use this in production. When you use the maven plugin it uses the deployment operations which deploys the archive to the running container.

If you're targeting JBoss EAP 6 you'll want to use the 6.4 branch of the quickstart repo, https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/6.4.x/helloworld-rs, which will use the `org.jboss.as.plugin:jboss-as` plugin instead.

JBoss EAP 6 is based on JBoss AS 7. JBoss AS was [renamed](https://www.redhat.com/en/about/press-releases/red-hat-reveals-plans-for-its-next-generation-java-application-server-project) to WildFly. JBoss EAP 7, which is the latest JBoss EAP release, is based on WildFly 10.